# How can I avoid implementing all IList members, and still have a base interface which implements a collection?

Tags: c#, list

How can I implement an easier solution, I'm looking for a better approach instead having to create a complex implementation class, appreciate some advice.

Current I'm doing the following:

```
public interface IAddressCollection : IList<IAddress>
{
      new void Add(IAddress address);    
}
```

so then I've got to implement everything something like the below the code. I want to avoid doing this, I'm looking for a simple way.

```
public class AddressCollection : IAddressCollection
{
    private List<IAddress> _data = new List<IAddress>();

    new public void Add(IAddress applicationAddress)
    {
        // some logic here... e.g.
        if (!this.Any(x => x.AddressType != applicationAddress.AddressType))
        {
            _data.Add(applicationAddress);
        }
    }
    // Plus all the members of IList
```

**EDIT**********

How can I avoid implementing all IList members, and still have a base interface which implements a collection?

*Furthermore how can u get 5 votes for "What's the question exactly?" seriously, if he gave me a half decent answer I'd give him/she a vote but not for question to a question.*

Comment: Uh ? I've written the question and an example of what I'm trying 2 do.

Comment: I find this question perfectly clear.  I have asked myself the exact same thing multiple times, spent some time looking for an answer, and never came up witth a good one.  Why has it been closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common approach would be to derive from `Collection<T>`:

```
public class AddressCollection : Collection<IAddress>, IAddressCollection
{
    public AddressCollection() : base(new List<IAddress>())
    {
    }
}
```

`Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`.

**UPDATE** in response to comments.

If you want to implement custom logic when adding or removing items, it's better to override one or more of the protected virtual methods `InsertItem`, `SetItem`, `RemoveItem` and `ClearItems`, rather than implementing a new `Add` method.

`InsertItem` is called whenever the public `Add` or `Insert` method is called to add an element to the list.  Similarly `SetItem` is called when an element is replaced (`myCollection[index] = newValue`), `RemoveItem` is called when the public `Remove` method is called and `ClearItems` when the public `Clear` method is called.

By doing this you will address the concern raised by Florian Greinacher in the comments - your custom logic will always be executed even if the list is used polymorphically as an `IList<IAddress>` or `Collection<IAddress>`

For example, to match your sample, you could ignore inserting / setting items that don't match a predicate with code something like the following (untested):

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, IAddress newItem)
{
    if (!this.Any(x => x.AddressType != newItem.AddressType)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, newItem);
    }
    else
    {
        // ... item does not match, do whatever is appropriate e.g. throw an exception
    }
}

protected override void SetItem(int index, IAddress newItem)
{
    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: thanks Joe that's exactly what I looking for, I appreciate the example.

Comment: But this way you will not be able to do your AddressType check without hiding the base implementation of Add - which you somehow requested in your question.

Comment: No disrespect you can, I've already implement Joe code and I've created a new method just I did in my example and it works perfectly without create a util class e.g. new public void Add(IAddress address){ .. same logic code.. } and I don't need to create a private variable and the extra noise. This is the ideal and correct approach, I just haven’t written these types of data contracts in over a year.

Comment: I said you cannot **without hiding the base implementation** by which I meant using the `new` modifier to declare a new `Add` method. This is definetely not the ideal solution because whenever your class will be passed around as e.g. `IList<IAddress>` or `IEnumerable<IAddress>` your custom, new-ed `Add` method will not be called.

Comment: I didn't consider the extensions approach because I'll be passing the dataContract to a client through WCF may not be concerned with the implementation and I didn't want to also provide a extensions library with the datacontracts. I jumped the gun with "ideal" but thanks @FlorianGreinacher its very good point and appreciate your feedback. I might need to reconsider the extensions approach.

Comment: +1 for the update, I did not know about those virtual methods on Collection<T>!

Answer (score 2):

Why did you want to hide the method `void Add(T item)`  declared in `IList<T>`? Just remove the method from `IAddressCollection` and everything will work fine.

Your implementing class can then look like this:

```
public class AddressCollection : IAddressCollection
{
    private List<IAddress> _data = new List<IAddress>();

    public void Add(IAddress applicationAddress)
    {
        if (!this.Any(x => x.AddressType != applicationAddress.AddressType))
        {
            _data.Add(applicationAddress);
        }
    }

    // Plus all other members of IAddressCollection
}
```

Comment: I kinda want to avoid implementing all member of IList, I just can't remember how do this correctly. cheers appreciate the example.

Comment: OK, if that's your point, I misunderstood the question, sorry. In the future when asking a question try to be more precise in terms of what you are trying to do / not to do and what your problem is.

Comment: No disrespect, but Joe got it. Sorry if wasn't clear enough.

Comment: No problem, my comment was just meant as a hint for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an extension method. You may want to come up with a better name.

```
public static class ListExtensions 
{
    public static bool TryAdd(this IList<IAddress> list, IAddress applicationAddress)
    {
        if (!list.Any(x => x.AddressType != applicationAddress.AddressType))
        {
            list.Add(applicationAddress);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what i'm after, I looking for way to implement interface with a List base, so I've got a strongly-typed datacontract to pass around. appreciate the example.